# Why was Lord Krishna in a confusion about who his parents were if he is almighty?

Tags: krishna, avatars

Lord Krishna is one of the most popular Gods in Hinduism. In the mythological story, Krishna did not know who his real parents were. We know Krishna is also the incarnation of Lord Vishnu. If he is almighty Lord Vishnu, why was he in a confusion about his parents?

Comment: Use body to explain your question in detail and in heading section, use short titles .

Comment: what 'mythological story' are you referring to ?

Comment: Haven't heard of any story in which he was in confusion!

Comment: Your question contains wrong information. Krishna knew who his parents were.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

He is never in illusion or confusion. Only uninformed think otherwise. 
Following statements from Bhagavata purana prove my point.

In relation to slaying of Salva demon, some sages thought Krishna was actually illusioned. Then following three verses refutes such conception.

> SB 10.77.30: Such is the account given by some sages, O wise King, but
>   those who speak in this illogical way are contradicting themselves,
>   having forgotten their own previous statements

Further these verses are spoken:

> SB 10.77.31: How can lamentation, bewilderment, material affection or
>   fear, all born out of ignorance, be ascribed to the infinite Supreme
>   Lord, whose perception, knowledge and power are all similarly
>   infinite?
>
> SB 10.77.32: By virtue of self-realization fortified by service
>   rendered to His feet, devotees of the Lord dispel the bodily concept
>   of life, which has bewildered the soul since time immemorial. Thus
>   they attain eternal glory in His personal association. How, then, can
>   that Supreme Truth, the destination of all genuine saints, be subject
>   to illusion?

Comment: This doesn't answer the question. The question is about whether Krishna knew who his biological parents were without being told about them. It's not about 'slaying of Salva demon'.

Comment: @sv. The Salva demon story concludes with generic verses which apply to Lord Krishna. So, yes he is never bewildered about his identity or his parents. Where he apparently appears to be bewildered is no more than lila for exchanging and expanding loving relations with devotees.

Answer (score 0):

But Krishna is not almighty. Ishwara is Shiva or Vishnu or Brahma or the Adi Parashakti accordingly to the angle of observation of the ultimate reality. Krishna is the 8th aavatar of Vishnu, embodied God Substance of His Immanence.
For the polytheists Hindu, this Ultimate Reality is expressed very well by the actions and tasks performed by the Gods in the Trimurti.

Sources: Sarvepalli Radakrishnan introduction to Bhagavad Geeta, Bhagavad Geeta itself, all the Upanisads quoted by Ramanuja and Sri Aurobindo related and inherent to the comments of ch 2, 8 and 12 in particular of Bhagavad Geeta. Abhinavagupta comment of Bhagavad Geeta.

*****DISCLAIMER

This answer has been given because it is wrong to say that Krishna is almighty or Rama is almighty. If you are a Vaishnavite you need to say that Maha Vishnu is the Almighty